# regarding netem

Tags: linux

when ever i try to execute the command for introducing the command to increase the packet drop rate the terminal shows an error
RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory
though the command for introducing the latency in  the network works perfectly fine..

Comment: First - Mention what commands you use. "The command to [foobar]"
doesn't exactly cut it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing happen... you need to execute your command as a super user:

```
sudo tc qdisc change dev ...
```